# castle monorails httpHandlers

Tags: .net, web-config, castle-monorail

I have a question and I hope you can help me solve it...
I have a castle monorails application. In web.config file in httphandlers I have *.aspx maped to monorails (my hosting does not suport other extensions...)

```
<add verb="*" path="*.aspx" type="Castle.MonoRail.Framework.MonoRailHttpHandlerFactory,Castle.MonoRail.Framework"/>
```

The problem is that I have some Webforms pages that I want to work with aspx... So I am adding something like this to the web.config file...

```
<add verb="*" path="connector.aspx*" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory"/>
<add verb="*" path="ChatPage.aspx*" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory"/>
<add verb="*" path="Logon.aspx*" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory"/>
```

Still it does not work.. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the order of the lines is important. Are the specific webforms handlers set before MonoRail's?  

It is usually a good suggestion to map an unused extension to MonoRail when in a mixed environment, to make life easier.

Comment: I have tried monorail's first and monorail's last and it is not working...

Comment: Have you tried mapping Monorail to *.ashx?  That's an ASP.NET default that should be supported by your host provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally fixed my problem creating a virtual directory where I have cleared the httphandlers

```
<httpHandlers><clear/>  

     <add verb="*" path="*.aspx" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory"/>

     <add verb="*" path="*" type="System.Web.HttpMethodNotAllowedHandler"/>
    </httpHandlers>

   <httpModules>
   <clear/>
    </httpModules>
```

and now it works ok...

Answer (score 0):

Why the asterisk on the end? You should have your monorail-section last, and the specific ones first. You don't need to worry about the query string.

However, maybe you need to take into account to whether they are in a sub-directory when you're being this specific.

like, `path="/folder/page.aspx"`